# Dupe answer in dupe question

Tags: discussion

I just noticed this question that seems a dupe.

[Access Denied Add-SPSolution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/access-denied-add-spsolution)

(original: [Sharepoint 2010 powershell add-spsolution access denied](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/7996/sharepoint-2010-powershell-add-spsolution-access-denied/))

I have voted it as so, but one more thing caught my eye: one of the [answers in the dupe](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/84663/5173) is the exact copy of an answer in the original question (see [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/7999/5173)).
How we should treat this? actually the copied answer provided a source... but I still believe that it should at least be reworded. Also to consider that if the 'copy-poster' founded the answer in another question on the same site, it probably would be better to mark the question as a dupe.

I am wondering what the common opinion is when working out such cases.

Comment: I appreciate your flag, and will compare questions later on. But I think we should keep all answers, even if they answer was made before the edit. Thanks!

Comment: @BennySkogberg - actually the problem is that the old question asked how to add a solution, the new one is about adding an SPShellAdmin. I was thinking about reversing the edit and then creating a new question for the new info (while keeping the old one closed as a dupe). Right now a reader would just find out how to add a solution while looking for something else.

Comment: @SPArceologist Sound like a plan. Reverse and keep as dupe. I'll do that when I'm not on iPhone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, I think it should be marked as duped, and if the question is in fact a little different, the link to the source answer is used first, maybe as a comment. Taking someone else's work as an answer from external links are fine as long as you source them, but I think that taking someone else's work from stack exchange degrades and steals the possible reputation and credit, even though it's sourced. It's one of those legal loopholes that I think should be frowned upon.

Comment: I agree that this is a loop hole, in many cases much harder to spot than this time too. What we can do, is to flag it as a duplicate. And if we feel the need to, make a commenting the duplicate answer about it and (more aggressive approach) down vote the duplicate answer. Down voting seems a bit hard here though, since there is a link to the source at least :)

Comment: I agree. I'm not one to down-vote, usually. Making the answer useful is the sole purpose of stack exchange, so if the person the asks the question is answered, with a successful solution, I think that is value.

Comment: @RobertLindgren - I agree about the downvote. Anyway, I would also have preferred if instead of copying the answer in two places, the question was marked as a duplicate in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Actions taken:

- Rolled back the question
- Locked the question for editing (24 hours)
- Blockquoted the answer
- Source changed to accepted answer instead of original question
- Locked the answer (24 hours)

Final desicion has not yet been made, stay tuned